# How to solve the following tricky question on differentiation and functions?

Tags: derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an infinitely differentiable function and suppose that
for some $n >1$,
$$
 f(1) = f(0) = f^{(1)}(0) = f^{(2)}(0) = \cdots = f^{(n)} (0) = 0
$$
where $f^{(k)}(x)$ denotes the $k$-th derivative of $f$ for $k \ge 1$.

Prove that there exists $x$ with $(0<x<1)$ such that $f^{(n+1)}(x) = 0$.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Answer (score 1):

By MVT, there is $c_1\in(0,1)$ such that $\displaystyle f^{(1)}(c_1)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=0$.

By MVT again, there is $c_2\in(0,c_1)$ such that $\displaystyle f^{(2)}(c_2)=\frac{f^{(1)}(c_1)-f^{(1)}(0)}{c_1-0}=0$.

By MVT again, there is $c_3\in(0,c_2)$ such that $\displaystyle f^{(3)}(c_3)=\frac{f^{(2)}(c_2)-f^{(2)}(0)}{c_2-0}=0$.

Repeat the process, we can construct $c_1,c_2,\dots, c_{n+1}$ such that $f^{(k)}(c_k)=0$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n+1$ and $1>c_1>c_2>\cdots>c_{n+1}>0$.

Answer (score 0):

[Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_in_one_real_variable)
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} (x - x_0)^k + R_n(x)
$$
and the [Lagrange form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)
$$
R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} (x - x_0)^{n+1}
$$
for some $\xi \in (x_0, x)$, applied at $x_0 = 0$ give
$$
0 = f(1)
= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} 1^k + R_n(1)
= R_n(1)
= \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}
$$
for some $\xi \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for another way of interpretation.